# Why doesn't this question "meet our quality standards"?

Tags: support, asking-questions, quality-filter

I've tried to ask this question both on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

> #### Is it possible to prove idempotence?
>
> Is it possible to use static or dependent types to prove a
> function is idempotent? If so, how would one do it?

I keep getting an error saying the question "does not meet our quality standards". This seems like a very reasonable question to me, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry about the loaded "quite reasonable" part. I had to come up with a title that hadn't been taken before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That certainly seems more of a [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) question. Stack Overflow is more for practical programming problems, that seems more of a hypothetical "[methods and practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" kind of question.

The Help Centre page [How do I ask a good question?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) clearly states:

> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Your question, although interesting, doesn't show any research or effort.

Do some research, show your efforts and explain as well as you can what you have found and why that didn't answer your question, giving as much detail as possible.